# Running sitespeed and Graphite with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, graphite, sitespeedio

I am running graphite, graphana and sitespeed using docker using this link for my application website: https://www.sitespeed.io/documentation/sitespeed.io/performance-dashboard/#up-and-running-in-almost-5-minutes.

Also I am able to send the metrics to Graphana using the docker-compose command. I have few queries -

- `docker-compose run sitespeed.io https://www.sitespeed.io/ --graphite.host=graphite` - This command only runs for one URL. How do i run this for multiple pages/urls? On sitespeed documentation it is written that we can create a file url.txt with each url in the new line but that is not working. It says **"urls.txt does not exist, is the path to the file correct?"** Where should this url.txt resides in order to run
- This command starts the container and stops it. How so i remove those containers to improve the housekeeping because I will be running this every hour in crontab.

Below is my docker-compose.yml which i downloaded from above link

```
version: '3'
services:
    sitespeed.io:
      image: sitespeedio/sitespeed.io
      command: -V
      shm_size: 1g
      volumes:
            - ./sitespeed-result/:/sitespeed.io/sitespeed-result
    grafana:
      image: grafana/grafana:6.6.2
      depends_on:
        - graphite
      links:
        - graphite
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      environment:
        - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=******
        - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=******
        - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=false
        - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
        - GF_USERS_ALLOW_ORG_CREATE=true
      volumes:
        - grafana:/var/lib/grafana
      restart: always
    graphite:
      image: sitespeedio/graphite:1.1.5-12
      ports:
        - "2003:2003"
        - "8080:80"
      restart: always
      volumes:
        # In production you should configure/map these to your container
        # Make sure whisper and graphite.db/grafana.db lives outside your containerr
        # https://www.sitespeed.io/documentation/sitespeed.io/graphite/#graphite-for-production-important
        - whisper:/opt/graphite/storage/whisper
        # Download an empty graphite.db from https://github.com/sitespeedio/sitespeed.io/tree/master/docker/graphite
        - graphite.db:/opt/graphite/storage/graphite.db
        #
        # And put the configuration files on your server, configure them as you need
        # Download from https://github.com/sitespeedio/docker-graphite-statsd/tree/master/conf/graphite
        # - /absolute/path/to/graphite/conf/storage-schemas.conf:/opt/graphite/conf/storage-schemas.conf
        # - /absolute/path/to/graphite/conf/storage-aggregation.conf:/opt/graphite/conf/storage-aggregation.conf
        # - /absolute/path/to/graphite/conf/carbon.conf:/opt/graphite/conf/carbon.conf
    grafana-setup:
      image: sitespeedio/grafana-bootstrap:12.1.0
      links:
        - grafana
      environment:
        - GF_PASSWORD=******
        - GF_USER=******
volumes:
    grafana:
    whisper:
```

Comment: Did you mount the urls file in the sitespeed docker container or put it in a mounted directory like `./sitespeed-result/` and reference the filepath in the container like `/sitespeed.io/sitespeed-result/urls.txt`?